# Question about little o calculations

Tags: calculus

I'm having a hard time understanding how little-o works in practice. For example I'd write $$\arctan^2x = [x+o(x)]^2=x^2+2xo(x)+(o(x))^2=x^2+o(x^2)+o(x^2)=x^2+o(x^2) $$ using $x^m\times o(x^n)= o(x^{n+m})$ and $[o(x^n)]^k=o(x^{nk})$ proprieties.
However my professor would say $$\arctan^2x=[x+o(x)]^2=x^2+o(x)+o(x)=x^2+o(x)$$
So I'm not really connecting the dots on why is the latter form the right one.

Comment: seems that your professor doesn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is formally right: starting from a *Taylor's expansion* at order $1$, the  general rules yield an expansion at order $1$. What your professor wrote ($x^2+o(x)$) is nothing but $o(x)$, which isn't very useful.

However, as $\arctan x$ has an expansion *without a constant term* and has no term in $x^2$, your result is perfectly correct: from an expansion at order $1$, you deduce an expansion  at order $2$ for the square.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right and the professor is wrong here. They probably got mixed up cause they were thinking in terms of $x\rightarrow\infty$ or big O.  Additionally, $x^2 + o(x)$ doesn't smell right since the error is potentially bigger than the main term.